# Finding parameter for which series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find out for which parameter $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x^n)
$$
converges. I thought about the series being a geometric series. Moving the index down to 0 should be no problem, as:
$$ (1-x^0) = 0 \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$$
(or is the fact that it's not working for $x=0$ destroying my idea?)
Now the constant 1 is in the way. Would moving the constant out of the sum be allowed:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1) - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^n)
$$
?

Or would it be easier to test the parameter a for for "interesting" values/intervals: $0$, $1$, $-1$, $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$? But this looks a bit "hacky" to me. (and might not cover special cases I did not think about)

Is there a better way?

Edit: $ (1-x^0) = 0 \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ was wrong as it's not true for $x=0$

Comment: For which $x$ does the term of the series converge to $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series converges for exactly one value: $x = 1$. For all other values, it fails the test that if 
$$
\sum a_i
$$
converges, then $\lim_{i \to \infty} a_i = 0$.

Comment: So because for every $x \neq 1$, $(1-x^n)$ is not a zero sequence, the series can only converge for $x=1$?
Note to myself: You can always think more complicated than necessary.
Thank you!

Comment: No. Because (for $x \ne 1$) the numbers $(1 - x^n)$ *do not approach a limit of zero*, the sequence cannot converge. To see that not all the numbers must be zero, look at $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \ldots$; the sum of this series exists and is 2, even though the individual terms are all nonzero. (Their limit, however, *is* zero, as required by the theorem I cited.)